# How does this iterative loop fit the model? ( Machine Learning)

Tags: python, loops, machine-learning

I'm confused as to what `for m in range(1, len(X_train)):`   is doing in the line `model.fit(X_train[:m], y_train[:m]) y_train_predict = model.predict(X_train[:m])` 
. So I think that m is going to loop over the size of the training data.and that for each loop m+=1 but I don't understand the rest

````
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

def plot_learning_curves(model, X, y):
    X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=10)
    train_errors, val_errors = [], []
    for m in range(1, len(X_train)):
        model.fit(X_train[:m], y_train[:m])
        y_train_predict = model.predict(X_train[:m])
        y_val_predict = model.predict(X_val)
        train_errors.append(mean_squared_error(y_train_predict, y_train[:m]))
        val_errors.append(mean_squared_error(y_val_predict, y_val))

    plt.figure(figsize=(8,4))
    plt.plot(np.sqrt(train_errors), "r-+", linewidth=2, label="Training set")
    plt.plot(np.sqrt(val_errors), "b-", linewidth=3, label="Validation set")
    plt.legend(loc="upper right", fontsize=14)   
    plt.xlabel("Training set size", fontsize=14) 
    plt.ylabel("RMSE", fontsize=14)      ```
````

Comment: you are right about `m` it will increment each time, so X_train[:m] is basically taking first m elements from X_train

Comment: @Sanchit.Jain so for iteration the model is fit with a different column of the training data ?

Comment: i'm assuming you have a data of size a x b where a are rows and b are columns, so this will take m rows of data each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purpose of this function is to show the performance of a model when trained with different sized datasets. Indexing an array with `X[:m]` selects the first `m` elements of `X` (along the first dimension if `X` is multi-dimensional). For each value of m in the for loop, it's saying "let's pretend we only had m data points, what would our training and validation accuracies be?". You should see that, for small m, the model would overfit so the training accuracy would be close to perfect and the validation accuracy would be very low. As `m` increases, the training accuracy will decrease, but the validation accuracy increase. The exact shapes of the curves are useful for diagnosing underfitting/overfitting.

Comment: Brilliant answer. Thank you. 

Just to clarify - With the  indexing of the array with '''X[:m]''' ,  I thought the indexing works as [rows : columbs] so '''[:m]''' would always use all the rows but the iterate over the columns. Have i got this wrong ?

Comment: No problem. That's not right, no. The indices for each dimension are separated by a comma, not a colon. Colons separate the start and end index, if both are used. Eg X[start_row:end_row, start_column:end_column]. X[:m] is all rows up to the mth, all columns.

Comment: Don't forget accept the answer if you found it helpful.

Comment: Have done :) And yes! I saw my mistake with the indexing. Thankyou for taking the time!